# Opening .hoc files in neuron simulator + "not a mechanism" problem

Tags: neuron-simulator

I am trying to run a NEURON simulation via python. I got all the libraries in order and am able to run some simple simulations, but am experiencing some troubles with a more complicated code. If you have any idea how to help I will appreciate it very much

**Problem number 1**:

Neuron doesn't open part of a `.hoc` file even though it is compiled. I get the error:

```
NEURON: Can't open  import3d/import3d_sec.hoc
in import3d.hoc near line 1
{xopen("import3d/import3d_sec.hoc")}
                                     ^
        xopen("import3d/i...")
      xopen("import3d.hoc")
    execute1("{xopen("im...")
  load_file("C:/Users/U...")
```

**Problem number 2:**

The simulator doesn't recognize a mechanism I am trying to use. here I am a bit lost and don't know to describe further, but this is the error message:

```
 NEURON: Im is not a MECHANISM
 in L5PCbiophys5b.hoc near line 26
    insert Im 
            ^
        xopen("L5PCbiophy...")
      execute1("{xopen("L5...")
    load_file("C:/Users/U...")
```

**Problem number 3**:

Not recognizing as a template:

```
 NEURON: Import3d_Neurolucida3 is not a template
 in L5PCtemplate_2.hoc near line 26
   nl = new Import3d_Neurolucida3()
                                  ^
        xopen("L5PCtempla...")
      execute1("{xopen("L5...")
    load_file("C:/Users/U...")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try to use an absolute path
2. The name for `insert` should match with the `SUFFIX` statement in the file; also make sure that file was compiled in and that the dll is loaded (should be a message when you start nrniv)
3. Perhaps a result of the file xopen problem?  If it is a template-containing file you should `use load_file()` instead of `xopen()`

Comment: This is a library function not a custom user-function. It should just be on the HOC path. It could be as simple as a clean install to fix the paths to the defaults.